# How to concatenate the BigInteger value with String

Tags: hibernate, groovy

I am converting the string value to BigInteger and trying to concatenate it with the String in a query but it always gives errors. `lookup and cols are of type BigInteger`

```
def getContentByPath(List<BigInteger> path, String filename) {
        int j = 1
        def q = "SELECT f.title, c.title, c.body FROM Content AS c, Folder AS f WHERE c.folderId = f.id "

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if (path[i] != null && path.size > 0) {
                q += " AND " + "f.col" + j + " = " + path[i]
            } else {
                q += " AND " + "f.col" + j + " = " + 0
            }
            j= j+1
        }
        q += " AND c.lookup = " + stb.toBigInt(filename)
        println q
        def result = em.createQuery(q).singleResult
        println result
        return result
    }
```

I have tried with several ways such as Long.parseLong, Integer.parseInt, etc,. still getting the same  exception `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "16731516642733300018"`

here is my stack trace.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "16731516642733300018"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:592) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:803) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.LiteralProcessor.determineIntegerRepresentation(LiteralProcessor.java:267) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.LiteralProcessor.processNumeric(LiteralProcessor.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processNumericLiteral(HqlSqlWalker.java:1079) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.literal(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3065) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.constant(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:5100) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1317) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4686) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4159) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2104) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2032) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2029) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2029) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2029) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2029) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2029) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2029) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2029) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2029) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2029) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:796) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:597) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:249) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:131) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1836) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344) ~[spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:293) ~[spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at javax.persistence.EntityManager$createQuery.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45) ~[groovy-all-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110) ~[groovy-all-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:122) ~[groovy-all-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.regionscms.services.PublicContentService.getContentByPath(PublicContentService.groovy:37) ~[bin/:na]
    at org.regionscms.services.PublicContentService$getContentByPath.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45) ~[groovy-all-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110) ~[groovy-all-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:130) ~[groovy-all-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.regionscms.publicInterceptor.PublicRequestInterceptor.postHandle(PublicRequestInterceptor.groovy:56) ~[bin/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain.applyPostHandle(HandlerExecutionChain.java:152) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:966) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:720) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:439) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:305) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:182) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]

2015-12-08 14:17:39.382 ERROR 9721 --- [nio-8099-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse literal [16731516642733300018] as integer
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:720) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:468) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:439) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:305) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:182) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse literal [16731516642733300018] as integer
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:331) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344) ~[spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:293) ~[spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at javax.persistence.EntityManager$createQuery.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45) ~[groovy-all-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110) ~[groovy-all-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:122) ~[groovy-all-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.regionscms.services.PublicContentService.getContentByPath(PublicContentService.groovy:37) ~[bin/:na]
    at org.regionscms.services.PublicContentService$getContentByPath.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45) ~[groovy-all-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110) ~[groovy-all-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:130) ~[groovy-all-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.regionscms.publicInterceptor.PublicRequestInterceptor.postHandle(PublicRequestInterceptor.groovy:56) ~[bin/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain.applyPostHandle(HandlerExecutionChain.java:152) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:966) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse literal [16731516642733300018] as integer
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.LiteralProcessor.determineIntegerRepresentation(LiteralProcessor.java:270) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.LiteralProcessor.processNumeric(LiteralProcessor.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processNumericLiteral(HqlSqlWalker.java:1079) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.literal(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3065) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.constant(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:5100) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1317) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4686) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4159) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2104) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2032) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2029) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2029) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2029) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2029) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2029) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2029) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2029) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2029) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2029) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:796) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:597) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:249) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:131) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1836) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    ... 50 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "16731516642733300018"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:592) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:803) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.LiteralProcessor.determineIntegerRepresentation(LiteralProcessor.java:267) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    ... 82 common frames omitted
```

method to convert toBigInt

```
public BigInteger toBigInt(String string) {
        // CONV(SUBSTRING(CAST(SHA(TRIM(LCASE("Home"))) AS CHAR), 1, 16), 16, 10)
        // SELECT CONV(SUBSTRING(CAST(SHA(TRIM(LCASE("Home"))) AS CHAR), 1, 16), 16, 10) AS result
        // If you run the above line in MySQL SELECT statement,  you'll get a result of 16731516642733300018
        return new BigInteger(stripAndFormatNonAlphaNumeric(string), 16);
    }

    // strip all non-alphanumeric characters from string
    private String stripAndFormatNonAlphaNumeric(String string) {
        try {
            // trim the string, lower case the string, replace non alphanumeric characters and
            // return the first 16 characters from the hex formatted string
            return toSHA1(string.trim().toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", " ").replaceAll("\\s+","-")).substring(0,16);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: that's the name of the function that I am using for converting the string to BigInteger.

Comment: Yeah, and how does the function look like?

Comment: @MuratK. -  I have updated my question

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace where you actually use `BigInteger`. This one shows that you are using `Long`.

Comment: `@Column(nullable=true, columnDefinition="bigint(20) unsigned default null")
 BigInteger lookup`

`@Column(nullable=true, columnDefinition="bigint(20) unsigned default null")
 BigInteger col1` these are my fields in the Content and Folder entities

Comment: Well I tested it and `new BigInteger("16731516642733300018", 16)` works. Can you post the stacktrace where you use the method `stb.toBigInt(filename)` and the value of `filenname` too?

Comment: `List<BigInteger> cols = new ArrayList<BigInteger>()
   
   String url = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI)
   List<String> dirPath = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(url.replaceAll("^/+", "").split("/")))`

`for (int i = 0; i < (dirPath.size-1); i++) {
    println dirPath[i]
    if (!dirPath.isEmpty()) {
     cols.add(stb.toBigInt(dirPath[i]));
    }
   }`

`def res = publicContentService.getContentByPath(cols, dirPath[dirPath.size - 1])` here I have created arrayList of type BigInteger and passing it to the method I have the above query.

Comment: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14860

Answer (score 1):

The max value of a Long is `9223372036854775807`. Your file name is presumably `16731516642733300018` which is a larger value.

You will need to either change the name of your filename or change the type of the column `lookup` on `Content` to `BigInteger`, which based on the stacktrace you have provided I assume it currently a `Long`.

Comment: `q += " AND " + "f.col" + j + " = " + path[i]` What is the type of `col<n>` on `Folder`? If that is `Long` then this applies to that as well as you are passing in `List<BigInteger>`.

Answer (score 1):

What is the type of the fields in the Folder entity?
I guess Long, but that it not long enough. Try making them BigInteger instead.

You say that they are already BigIntegers.
So maybe try changing the query to use named parameters: `q += " AND " + "f.col" + j + " = :col" + i`, and then call `setParameter("col" + i, path[i])` in another loop after creating the query, but before calling `singleResult` on it.

```
def q = em.createQuery(q)
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    q.setParameter("col" + i, path[i])
}
def result = em.createQuery(q).singleResult
```

Comment: how can I use setParameter inside the for loop ?

Answer (score 0):

Max value for `java.lang.Long` is `9223372036854775807`, and `16731516642733300018` is bigger than that.

Comment: He is using BigInteger tho

Comment: The stacktrace shown uses `Long.parseLong` somewhere inside hibernate, so this observation is correct.

Comment: @Predrag Maric @Mark Rotteveel - I have figured that JPQL query not accepting BigInteger value `SELECT f.title, c.title, c.body FROM Content AS c, Folder AS f WHERE c.folderId = f.id AND col1 = 16731516642733300018` I have hard coded the value for testing I found that it is not accepting BigInteger value. is it my assumption is right ?

Comment: @Sulemankhan JDBC doesn't support BigInteger, so it has to apply some conversion.

Comment: OH i see, could you please share any idea or tip to convert it in the query itself ? I have tried to use `CAST(16731516642733300018 AS unsigned)` but no works.

Answer (score 0):

Suffix “BI“ ("12345678901234567890BI") allows to solve my issue, may be someone find this as solution too.